Trying to identify a 90s thriller/action movie
At the start, a guy on a bike got hit by a bus. He had a disk with secret information on it that both a gang and the FBI wanted. The FBI were willing to pay the gang for the disk. Then, near the end, there was a massive shoot-out between the FBI and the gang in a restaurant where everyone was killed apart from one guy who hid under a table. 

Hi! Welcome to Movies & TV, and thanks for your question! I hope we can answer it for ya! You've actually already done pretty good in terms of providing the decade the movie is from (most new members don't think to do that). But it would also be helpful to add any other information you know - e.g. language, what country you think it was from, etc. (There's an edit button below your post if you want to make changes.) Thanks!

ENEMY OF THE STATE. Staring Will Smith and Jon Voight. The guy on bike played by Jason Lee(my name is Earl) plants footage of an assassination on Will Smith in a lingerie store. It ends in shoot out between government agents and mob goons at restaurant run by Tom Sizemore. Will Smith hid under table and survived whole ordeal. Gene Hackman is in it to, during final scenes hes dressed as cop with bloody hand and has a cat.

YEP! Definitely "Enemy of the State". Also Seth Green and I think Jack Black are the little hacker guys that are moving all the cameras around tracking Will Smith's character. I forgot how many stars are in this movie.
